# Jumping Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

A jumping number is defined as a positive number n which all pairs of consecutive decimal digits differ by 1. Also, all single digit numbers are considered jumping numbers. eg. 3, 45676, 212 are jumping numbers but 414 and 13 are not. The difference between 9 and 0 is not considered as 1

**The challenge**
Create a program that output one of the following results:

- Given an input `n` output the first `n` jumping numbers.
- Given an input `n` output the `n`<sup>th</sup> term of the sequence.

**Note**

- Any valid I/O format is allowed
- 1-index or 0-index is allowed (please specify)

Here are some jumping numbers:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 21, 23, 32, 34, 43, 45, 54, 56, 65, 67, 76, 78, 87, 89, 98, 101, 121, 123, 210, 212, 232, 234, 321, 323, 343, 345, 432, 434, 454, 456, 543, 545, 565, 567, 654, 656, 676, 678, 765, 767, 787, 789, 876, ...
```

This is also [A033075](https://oeis.org/A033075)

Comment: Is this 0 or 1 Indexed?

Comment: @TaylorScott The sequence consists in only positive numbers. If you mean the input `n` then it is up to you.

Comment: I'm guessing "Any valid I/O format is allowed" includes outputting the numbers as lists of decimal digits, but just wanted to confirm - ?

Comment: Yes @JonathanAllan

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 bytes

```hs
(l!!)
l=[1..9]++[x*10+t|x<-l,t<-[0..9],(mod x 10-t)^2==1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyNHUVGTK8c22lBPzzJWWzu6QsvQQLukpsJGN0enxEY32gAkrqORm5@iUKFgaKBbohlnZGtrGPs/NzEzT8FWoaAoM69EQUUhN7FAIU0BrNwy9v@/5LScxPTi/7rJBQUA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
1DI*`ƑƊ#
```

A full program accepting an integer, `n`, from STDIN which prints a list of the first `n` positive jumping numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QxVMr4djEY13K//@bmgAA)**

#### How?

Acceptable incremental differences between digits are `1` and `-1` while others from `[-9,-2]+[2,9]` are not. This lines up with integers which are invariant when raised to themselves. i.e. \$x^x=x\$ since:

$$0^0=1$$
$$1^1=1$$
$$2^2=4$$
$$\cdots$$
$$-1^{-1}=-1$$
$$-2^{-2}=-\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\cdots$$

```
1DI*`ƑƊ# - Main Link: no arguments (accepts a line of input from STDIN)
       # - count up keeping the first (input) n matches...
1        - ...start with n equal to: 1
      Ɗ  - ...match function: last three links as a monad:  e.g. 245       777      7656
 D       -   convert to a list of decimal digits                 [2,4,5]   [7,7,7]  [7,6,5,6]
  I      -   incremental differences                             [2,1]     [0,0]    [-1,-1,1]
     Ƒ   -   invariant under?:
    `    -     using left argument as both inputs of:
   *     -       exponentiation (vectorises)                     [4,1]     [1,1]    [-1,-1,1]
         -                                            --so we:   discard   discard  keep
         - implicitly print the list of collected values of n
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 5 bytes

The input is 1-indexed.

#### Code:

```
µN¥ÄP
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Fa/Q0sPtwT8/29qAAA)

#### Explanation

```
µ          # Get the nth number, starting from 0, such that...
   Ä       #   The absolute values
 N¥        #   Of the delta's of N
    P      #   Are all 1 (product function, basically acts as a reduce by AND)
```

Comment: Right tool for the job.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>79</s> 75 bytes

*-4 bytes by xnor*

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:n and-~f(n-g(i),i+1)
g=lambda i:i<10or i%100%11%9==g(i/10)>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcyxCsIwGATgvU9xSyDBFPPrZGl8keIQqYk/6N8S2sHFV48p6OR0cHx382u5T3IoJfpHeF7HALHsqRMEGdt31NImzcbyjkyTfoY77slNGazIOUWkTt5Xtydnzq6s8BgYcQNgQQ6SbppstQYcsT1emjmzLFi/OcRa/k@OVGX5AA)

Derived from [Chas Brown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69880/chas-brown)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180715/39328). The helper function `g(i)` returns whether `i` is a jumping number. Iff the last two digits of a number `n` have absolute difference 1, then `n%100%11` will be either 1 or 10, so `n%100%11%9` will be 1.

Comment: Nice trick with the `%11`. You can do `f=lambda n,i=1:n and-~f(n-g(i),i+1)` if you switch to one-indexing.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

1-indexed. Thanks to dzaima for their help with golfing this.

Edit: -15 bytes from ngn.

```apl
1+⍣{∧/1=|2-/⍎¨⍕⍺}⍣⎕⊢0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKNdIe2/ofaj3sXVjzqW6xva1hjp6j/q7Tu04lHv1Ee9u2qBMo/6pj7qWmQAUsyV9qhtAlDa8FHPXvXaanUddaAkCBepP@rdqg5UZvSoZzuQn1yknqau8Kh3rkJJUWJKWp5CSb4CkPpfDVSmYPiodwuIoZMGJGpBVm0GMYwNAA)

**Explanation**

We have `f⍣g⍣h`, where, as `⍣` is an operator, APL translates this to `(f⍣g)⍣h`. (In contrast with functions where `2×3+1` is translated `2×(3+1)`)

```apl
1+⍣{...}⍣⎕⊢0  This is equivalent to 
               "do {check} we find the n-th integer that fulfils {check}"

1+⍣{...}   ⊢0  Start with 0 and keep adding 1s until the dfn 
               (our jumping number check in {}) returns true.
        ⍣⎕    We take input n (⎕) and repeat (⍣) the above n times 
               to get the n-th jumping number.

{∧/1=|2-/⍎¨⍕⍺}  The dfn that checks for jumping numbers.

         ⍎¨⍕⍺   We take the base-10 digits of our left argument
                 by evaluating each character of the string representation of ⍺.
     |2-/        Then we take the absolute value of the pairwise differences of the digits
 ∧/1=            and check if all of the differences are equal to 1.
```

Comment: `10⊥⍣¯1⊢⍺` -> `⍎¨⍕⍺`

Comment: it's much shorter with `⍣` instead of recursion: `{1+⍣{∧/1=|2-/⍎¨⍕⍺}⍣⍵⊢0}` or `1+⍣{∧/1=|2-/⍎¨⍕⍺}⍣⎕⊢0`

Comment: "⍣ is an operand" - it's an "operator" (i this mistake in chat and corrected it, but it seems you picked up the initial version. sorry)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 90 bytes

```c
f(n,K,b,k){for(K=0;n;b&&printf("%d,",K,n--))for(b=k=++K;k/10;)b*=abs(k%10-(k/=10)%10)==1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoQwDAD/IiiJttgeJeQFfYWpVCRsVtTbsm/vdm8zMEz2e861FjCXnDjFT3lfkDiQkQzDeR32FOj6zXUtMO8R/4Gw8jQl0jkGQhl5lRu0j8GDzhwDNkTmSN/6Wg@DtoVlwaY/)

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 14 bytes

Outputs the first `n`th term, 1-indexed.

```
_ì äa dÉ ªU´}f
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=X+wg5GEgZMkgqlW0fWY=&input=NTQ=)

(I know, I know, [I'm supposed to be taking a break](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17410/58974) but I'm in golf withdrawal!)

Comment: Haha, maybe go learn a new golfing language to cure your withdrawal. :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 69 bytes

- Thanks to [Joseph Sible](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81540/joseph-sible) for enforcing the challenge rules and saving three bytes.
- Saved two bytes thanks to [nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi).

```hs
(filter(all((==1).abs).(zipWith(-)<*>tail).map fromEnum.show)[1..]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcmxCoMwEADQX6ngcFfwqKNg3PoFDh2sw1VMc/SiIYkU@vFNoW99jtNrVS3W3AtY0bxGYFUAY1okfiQk@Ei4SXbQYH8eMosieQ4nG3d/3Q5Pye1vnFqiuaqweJbNhCOPOf6ntn09TBeirpvLd7HKz1SaJYQf)

Comment: This appears to answer the question "is this a jumping number?" for a given input number, which isn't what the challenge asked for.

Comment: @JosephSible You are correct. Thank you for noting.

Comment: Also, now that that's fixed, you can make `g` 3 bytes shorter by rewriting it to be pointfree, then using `<*>`: `g=all((==1).abs).(zipWith(-)<*>tail).map(read.pure).show`

Comment: @JosephSible Thank you.

Comment: @nimi Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=2:n and f(n-g(i),i+1)or~-i
g=lambda i:i<10or abs(i/10%10-i%10)==1==g(i/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBCsIwEETv/Yq9CAm2mK234n5J8ZBSEwd0W9L24MVfj1H04mUGHm9mfqzXSducg9z8fRg9aQ1pOyWvIwWjTTSwNfZsp/RsUMWfhw4ndlMiPywGB3Y7dg1KWBEWiR9m80ZCPSgUEQSl5DVeDNfsnCUEet@fqzlBV9q@3YcC/ydHV7z8Ag)

Returns the 0-indexed jumping number (i.e., f(0) => 1, etc).

Comment: @lirtosiast : That's OK, please donate your answer to your favorite charity :). It's sufficiently different to merit a separate response (as well as being cross-language appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

*-1 by Jonathan Allan*

```
1DạƝ=1ẠƲ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Q5eGuhcfm2ho@3LXg2Cbl//9NjAA)

1-indexed.

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Q5eGuhcfm2ho@3LXg2Cbl//9NjAA) by reading STDIN

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 60 bytes

Returns the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> term of the sequence (1-indexed).

```javascript
f=(n,k)=>[...k+''].some(p=x=>(p-(p=x))**2-1)||n--?f(n,-~k):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsIwEADvfcUeCs22JlChF2vqQ0RoqIlo6iY0IkIbvx7jaeYw81BvFabl7l@c3FWnZCSjnUU5nIUQtqmqiwjuqZmXHzkwz/@CWNd73uK2Eecnkwf@tXiwybiFEUhoeyA4QtdlNg3CWgBMjoKbtZjdjY2KlStFzGm55h/jiH0R0w8)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 228 bytes

```
func j(n:Int){
var r:[Int]=[]
for x in 0...n{
if x<=10{r.append(x)}else{
let t=String(x).compactMap{Int(String($0))}
var b=true
for i in 1...t.count-1{if abs(t[i-1]-t[i]) != 1{b=false}}
if b{r.append(x)}
}
}
print(r)
}
j(n:1000)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY@/CsIwEMb3PMUJDsnQkIBTMQ/g4ORYOqQ1kUiNIb1qIfTZ61Vc5Ib7x32/78Z38HhYVz/FHu481qeIorCXzZDrhprWNC3zzwwzhAhKShkLCx7mo9GqZGlTcvHKZ7G4YXSFDQ4BzQVziDeayv75SLbHs02F1PhvsVdCLF9KZzBP7ksIG0ETAelqiljpQiDbjRybUOm2otQK2BnQpTPeEm9ZNi/dnw@2RSIM8iyo3L7SSimxrh8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>122</s> 121 bytes

```python
g=lambda s:len(s)==1or 1==abs(ord(s[0])-ord(s[1]))and g(s[1:])
def f(n,i=1):
	while n:
		if g(str(i)):n-=1;yield i
		i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBCsMgEIXhdXIKlzO0gQztyjInCVkY1ESwY1Ch9PQ20t338975rUeSR2s7R/PerFFFRydQkJlSVsRstgIpWyjLvOL0F62IRqzau/WKo3VeeZB7YEI9Dp8jRKfk0hB8f9UMAVHLxPQ6c5B6ZR9vTM3Dc8b2Aw)

-1 byte by changing `f` from printing, to a generator function.

`g` is a recursive helper function which determines if a string `s` is a "jumping string" (this works since the character codes for 0 to 9 are in order and contiguous).

`f` is a generator function that takes in `n` and yields the first `n` jumping numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 85 bytes

```r
i=scan();j=0;while(i)if((j=j+1)<10|all(abs(diff(j%/%10^(0:log10(j))%%10))==1))i=i-1;j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoMwEAXQ0wT@R0pntqZzFSHaRmcILeiiG@8efcu39@52LOUL5jDJ/83bB06vQFgMypfKWVpDmQ@8vVZEeiaVCTK236qCINMdpJmSbv7QHF1F@gU)

Suspect this can be golfed more. Reads the number using `scan()` and outputs the appropriate jumping number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 56 bytes

```perl
map{1while++$n=~s|.(?=(.))|abs$&-$1!=1|ger>9}1..<>;say$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saDasDwjMydVW1slz7auuEZPw95WQ09TsyYxqVhFTVfFUNHWsCY9tcjOstZQT8/Gzro4sVIl7/9/Q@N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

1-indexed, outputs the n<sup>th</sup> jumping number

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 85 bytes

```
If[#<10,#,t=n=1;While[t<=#,{-1,1}~SubsetQ~Differences@IntegerDigits@n++~If~t++];n-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsMgEADQXykIXTSQmxPBIYtbS4cO4mDDaQ6aG/Q6lfrr9r0zyYFnEtrTKHb4HNQKs1FGLFtYnge9MchqlflOYODXH59XQ7n3jXLGirxjc54FC9aNCklzrHX3uYvWceEJ4nXcKrFcXAkwz3GMPw)

returns the n-th number

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 129 bytes

```
: f ( x -- ) 1 [ [ dup 10 >base >array differences [ abs 1 = ] all? ] [ 1 + ] until
dup . 1 + [ 1 - ] dip over 0 > ] loop 2drop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xTsNADIb3PsU/glAqimBJRTuiLl0QU9TBzfnoqUfusB1Enz51U1my/X@yPjlSb0Wmr8/d/qPFmWXgjCpsdqmSBsMP2WlZSZTlvquRJbXUK0iELjpjKP@OPPSsWC92@xZ9CfxdcpxaRDzgH02DR6zQeYWxYvWMzZGUsZktCClGlruhAx3Vb99xAOW89dF5fPI5Dpby4iZYzuTGG@chVZQ//9G1HnMpFS9BvK@nt1fE6Qo)

Outputs the first `n` jumping numbers

Answer (score 1):

## [Catholicon](https://github.com/okx-code/Catholicon), 5 bytes

```
ρHṘḃǰ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sycjPyUzOz/v//3yjx8OdMx7uaD6@4f9/Q0MA)